# Should I start to use CSS 3 & HTML 5?

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, css, web-standards

I fear this may sound subjective, sorry.

I am wondering how "safe" it is to use CSS3 & HTML5 in a commercial app. I really want the power that they give, but am obviously wary that they are not completely standardized.

If it helps any I can probably enforce the use of Chrome as the browser; I can likely offer FireFox as an alternative. I personally do not want to let the user choose their own browser and can probably enforce my choice in a corporate environment which is already heavily biased towards Google.

I suppose that if I can enforce a Chrome only policy & carefully test before release then my only worry is that some "behaviour" may change in future.

Would you risk it, or would play safe (or go with an alternative, such as a Java app, forgetting the browser)?

---

Can anyone suggest a forum where this question might be welcomed? Thanks.

(I accept that it might be too subjective for this site, sorry)

Comment: Closing as NARQ, and not just because it's subjective - you've literally given no detail at all on what the app is about, other than the fact that its commercial. How can we advice you what technology and solution to use if that's all the information you give us?

Comment: You might want to read Dive Into HTML5 by Mark Pilgrim (http://diveintohtml5.org/).  The first few chapters might help you decide whether or not to go with HTML5.

Comment: try to give more detail about what is are the features you would like to use in HTML5 and CSS3 and besides i don't think targeting a few browsers is a very good option..

Comment: +1 But ... 'i don't think targeting a few browsers is a very good option.."   Sometimes corporate policy enforces the use of a single browser, so why expend effort on the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a commercial product, I would not rely on unfinished specifications such as HTML5 and CSS3. Nor would I try and 'enforce' the use of a particular browser.

By all means try and enhance your site using CSS3, but don't rely on it.

Answer (score 5):

http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/ ?

Use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) so your site would be [gracefully degradable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system).

Comment: Progressive enhancement and graceful degradation are very different things.

Comment: +1 But I can actually state that a given browser/browser version be used, if I wish to.